# Getting Error while updating table data in Dynamodb table using boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to update to dynamo DB table using boto3. Getting below error while updating.

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object.

```
table = dynamodb.Table('user_data')
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            'userName': userName
        },
        UpdateExpression='SET userPass  = :val1',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':val1': make_password(newPasswd)
        }
    )
```

Comment: The “TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object” error is raised when you try to unpack values from one that is equal to None.  You didn't say what line this was occurring, but check the values of `make_password(newPasswd)`, `userName` and `newPasswd` to ensure they are what you expect.

Comment: I found out the issue, the issue was in my code only. It was a silly mistake, Thanks for the help @SethGeoghegan

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  Consider sharing the resolution to your problem, in case someone else has the same silly mistake.  It happens to all of us :)